# Characterising minors of diagonal matrices

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, determinant, exterior-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $k,d$ be positive integers, $1<k<d$. Let $\lambda_I=\lambda_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ be real numbers, indexed by multi-indices $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$, where $1\le i_1<\ldots<i_k \le d$.

Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $\lambda_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ which are equivalent to the existence of $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}=\sigma_{i_1}\cdot \ldots\cdot\sigma_{i_k}$ holds for every multi-index $I$?

> In other words, I am asking whether we can characterise which sequences of real numbers can arise as the $k$-minors of **diagonal** $d \times d$ matrices?

I am interested mainly in the case where all the $\lambda_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ are non-zero.

I have heard that the general problem of recognizing $k$-minors of arbitrary square matrices is open, but I am hoping that for *diagonal* matrices, the situation maybe better understood.

I guess this should be easier by starting over $\mathbb{C}$. What is known about that case?

*Commnet:* If I understand correctly, the [Plucker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding#Pl%C3%BCcker_relations) only describe the minors of **top-degree** of a non-square matrix. Here I am talking about the minors of degree $k$, when $1<k<d$, i.e. non-top minors of a *square matrix*.

Comment: I guess you mean $\lambda_{i_1, \dots, i_k} = \sigma_{i_1} \cdot ... \cdot  \sigma_{i_k}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you! corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give an answer over complex numbers.
The conditions are the following: for each pair $i \ne j$ and for each pair of subsets $I,J \subset \{1,\dots,d\} \setminus \{i,j\}$ of cardinality $k - 1$ one has a relation
$$
\lambda_{I \sqcup \{i\}} \cdot \lambda_{J \sqcup \{j\}} = 
\lambda_{I \sqcup \{j\}} \cdot \lambda_{J \sqcup \{i\}}.
$$
Clearly these relations are necessary.

Let us also show that they are sufficient. In fact, let me just explain how $\sigma_i$ can be reconstructed. Take any set $J \subset \{1,\dots,d-1\}$ of cardinality $k$. Then set
$$
\sigma_d = \sqrt[k]{\frac{\prod_{j \in J} \lambda_{J \setminus \{j\} \sqcup \{d\}}}{\lambda_J^{k-1}}}.
$$
After that for each $i \in \{1,\dots,d-1\}$ choose $J \subset \{1,\dots,d-1\} \setminus \{i\}$ of cardinality $k-1$ and set
$$
\sigma_i = \frac{\prod_{j \in J} \lambda_{J \setminus \{j\} \sqcup \{i,d\}}}{\lambda_{J \sqcup \{i\}}^{k-2}\sigma_d^{k-1}}.
$$
One can check that this solves the required equations.

Over real numbers the only extra problem is the existence of the root.

Comment: I think we have $k$ fixed.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: You are right, I will change the answer.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Thanks for correction!

Comment: If $k$ is even, don't we have to be careful with the choice of the sign of $\sigma_d$? How do you know that you can pick the positive? Respectively, that you can take the kth root of the expression?

Comment: Also, are you sure your conditions imply that $\sigma_d$ is really well-defined? i.e. is truly independent of the initial subset $J$ chosen? (I tried showing this follows from your conditions but failed..., though maybe I am too tired and hence confusing indices...). Anyway, your solution seems very nice, and even though it may look 'obvious' that it's correct (and I think I can follow its spirit), I am having trouble verifying rigorously that it works.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I will just note that when you work over the complex numbers, you don't really have a problem: Instead of possible non-existence of roots (in the real case), you now have too many of them. However, it does not matter "which one you choose", since choosing a different $k$-th root only amounts to multiplying all the $\sigma_i$ by some specific $k$-th root of unity, which is the only ambiguity we have here. (This was to be expected in advance, as I will elaborate in the question).

Comment: @AsafShachar Of course, sorry, I missed the obvious.